# A word for Bashfully Giddy?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word to describe a feeling. The best I can describe it is bashfully giddy. Like, I want to show of this elated smile but I also kind of want to bury my head in the sand. It's as though being so happy makes me shy? There has to be a word for it....

Comment: ecstatic? This means "an overwhelming sense of happiness"

Comment: _giggling_ is sort of a shy, suppressed, nervous happiness; a sort of stifled laughter. Traditionally, the term _giggling (or giggly_) was mainly applied to girls or young women.

Comment: It's an _ambivalent_ state (but there are probably many).

Answer (score 1):

I love the description of 'bashfully giddy' but it's pretty tough to find a single word to convey it. Feelings in general are hard to convey in single words.

The closest I can think of are these (they're related).. [blush](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/blush?s=t) or [erubescent](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/erubescent)